# Permission denied error for "ls" operation on SFTP server through Java API

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, ioexception

I've an SFTP server with appropriate credentials setup.

I've an admin user on that machine, which has certain rights to perform certain actions.
So, I've edited the sudoers file to add action like this

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers

# Added the below line at end of file
admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/ls
```

I want to list down a directory and get the count of files in that directory through Java API.

```
    SFTPv3Client client = null;
    try {
        client = new SFTPv3Client(connection); // connection is successful.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Vector list = null;
    try {
        list = client.ls(directoryName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // throws IOException 
    }
```

I've used `ch.ethz.ssh2.SFTPv3Client` jar. I'm able to connect to server and also authenticate through username and password.

But, when listing down the directory, I face below error

```
ch.ethz.ssh2.SFTPException: Permission denied (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.)
```

Does anybody have an idea about the cause of this issue ?

Comment: Does it work when you do an ls after logging in as the same user?

Comment: No. I get the same "permission denied" exception when doing ls operation with that user on that directory.

Comment: That means the user does not have enough permissions.

Comment: Can't you use session.execCommand and pass "sudo ls" to it?

Comment: Assuming you're using Ganymed.